# Gitlab - sync online repo with a remote server?

Tags: gitlab

I am working on a small team and we are using a Centralized Workflow strategy where we each have a local copy of the project. We then commit and push to Gitlab.

The server actually running the code (ETL scripts) is completely separate though. Currently, we use PyCharm to manage version control and there is a checkbox which syncs the file to a specified remote server. This has worked fine for the most part, but it is not ideal if multiple people are working on the same project - when a commit is made it will transfer and overwrite the file on the remote server.

What is the best way for me to make sure that the remote server which runs the ETL scripts only uses the master branch for each project directly from Gitlab? This way, we can make sure only 'finalized' code is used and we can address any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a crontab to achieve this and it works.

```
crontab -e
```

Custom schedule to navigate to the parent directory, then loop through all sub-folders and git pull every 5 minutes. If anyone sees any huge flaws, let me know.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /path/to/folder && for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git pull; ); done
```